# Azure API call: response contains html page

Tags: angularjs, azure, redirect, backend

I created an API app that is hosted in Azure and protected by the Active Directory (when I open the url in a browser, I get redirected to a login page from microsoft).
Now I have an angular app that should get the data from the api. I protected the angular app with the Actice Directory, too. In this manner I want to get a token which I can use for authentication.

API call:

```
const auth = btoa("[my username]:[my password]");

var token;
if((window.location.href).indexOf('/') != -1) {
  var queryString = (window.location.href).substr((window.location.href).indexOf('/') + 1); 
  token = (queryString.split('='))[1];
  token = decodeURIComponent(token);
}

$http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + auth;
$http.defaults.useXDomain = true;
$http.defaults.headers.common['x-ms-token-aad-id-token'] = token;
delete $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];


var erg = $http.get('http://[app name].azurewebsites.net/api/contacts')
.success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
      $scope.loggedIn = "LOGGED IN";
      $scope.responseData = data;
})
.error(function (data, status, header, config) {
      console.log("ERROR");
});
```

I had to open Chrome with disabled 'same origin policy'.

The data that was returned:

```
<html><head><title>Working...</title></head>
<body>
    <form method="POST" name="hiddenform" action="https://[app name].azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback"><input type="hidden" name="id_token" value="eyJ0[...]NBw" />
        <input type="hidden" name="state" value="/api/contacts#" />  
        <input type="hidden" name="session_state" value="fdbe7ee3-[...]-b12663d39846" />
        <noscript><p>Script is disabled. Click Submit to continue.</p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></noscript>
    </form>
    <script language="javascript">document.forms[0].submit();</script>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I get the JSON data that the API should actually return? What can I do with this html snippet?

Comment: You should check this tutorial: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-devquickstarts-angular/. You need to authenticate with Azure AD first to get an access token to call your API. And you should never have your password in front-end JavaScript..

Comment: Have you tried to use https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js to get the token and leverage it to call your resource protected by AAD

Comment: Yes, I tried it. I get the token (in the url...), but I can't access the API. Actually I don't know where I should put the token.

Comment: Hi @chocolatecake, do you have any update for now?

Comment: Hi Gary Liu. The update: I can get a bearer token (I think this is what I need) when I send a request with a java application. With my web application it doesn't work because of CORS policy.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the sample in https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js to integrate adal in your SPA. The SDK has implemented the functionalities acquiring access token from AAD. And also will intercept the http requests in Angularjs and add the authentication header.

You can refer to http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2015/02/19/introducing-adal-js-v1/ & http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/10/28/adal-javascript-and-angularjs-deep-dive/ for further understanding of adal for js.

And to make sure your SPA can call your APIs in server. You can try following configurations in Angualrjs config section:

```
app.config(['$locationProvider', 'adalAuthenticationServiceProvider', '$httpProvider', function($locationProvider, adalAuthenticationServiceProvider, $httpProvider) {
            $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
            $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
            var endpoints = {
                "http://garycors.azurewebsites.net": "bce85948-9ea4-4738-b1e6-972f3d30f4da",
                // "http://garycors.azurewebsites.net": "90e54701-ff93-414c-b7ee-c2d9b01417f3",
            };
            adalAuthenticationServiceProvider.init({
                    tenant: "<tenant_id>", // Optional by default, it sends common
                    clientId: "<client_id>", 
                    cacheLocation: 'sessionStorage'
                },
                $httpProvider // pass http provider to inject request interceptor to attach tokens
            );
            $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpRequestInterceptor');
    }]);

 app.factory('httpRequestInterceptor', function () {
          return {
            request: function (config) {

              config.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + sessionStorage.getItem("adal.idtoken");

              return config;
            }
          };
        });
```

Any further concern, please feel free to let me know.